# Change input value based on another input's value

Tags: javascript, forms, cakephp

I want to have a form which will have a couple of inputs, for example: name and url.

When the user enters their name, I'd like the url input to automatically have as a default their name with an underscore between words. So if they type in as their name pedro kinkybottom then automatically set as the default in the url input would be pedro_kinkybottom.

I'm using cakephp if anyone happens to know a particularly cakey way to do this that'd be cool but otherwise any help at all would be most welcome.

Comment: why looking for PHP solution, this can be done easily with javascript!

Comment: +1 for unique names Mr Pedro Kinkybottom and Sammy Sausage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably want to do this in JavaScript and not in PHP.  Even though you may be more familiar with the latter, the user experience would be better with the former and the overall design simpler (since the page wouldn't need to refresh).

You essentially need to do two things:

1. Set the value of an input in response to an event on another input.
2. Replace space characters with underscore characters.

For the second part, take a look at JavaScript's [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.  It's pretty robust and lets you do a lot of string manipulation.  Definitely worth trying it out yourself.

For the first part, here's an example with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('#inputName').change(function() {
  $('#inputURL').val($('#inputName').val());
});
```

This would set the value of `inputURL` to the value of `inputName` any time the value of `inputName` changes.  For the string replacement, you'd modify it similar to this:

```
$('#inputName').change(function() {
  $('#inputURL').val($('#inputName').val().replace(' ', '_'));
});
```

Note that the `change` event will be fired when the control loses focus.  If you want to to happen as-you-type then try the `keyup` event.  There are [other events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) as well.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Looks like I've got a bit of reading for after dinner then! Thanks :)

Comment: @sammy sausage: No problem, good luck with your development efforts.  Personally I've enjoyed JavaScript development more than anything other technology in my career :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a keyup event to the name field that will update the url field:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="text" id="url" />
</form>
```

...and the js:

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('name'), 'keyup', function () {
   document.getElementById('url').value = this.value.replace(' ', '_');
});


function addEvent(ele, evnt, funct) {
  if (ele.addEventListener) // W3C
    return ele.addEventListener(evnt,funct,false);
  else if (ele.attachEvent)  // IE
    return ele.attachEvent("on"+evnt,funct);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XKEh5/

If you're only going to do some trivial stuff like this, then you'll be fine with plain old javascript. If you're going to be doing a lot of this sort of thing, plus any effects like fading out elements or whatnot, I suggest you look in to [mootools](http://mootools.net/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Hi, cheers for the reply. I've been hearing a lot about jquery so will be defo having a more thorough investigation.

Comment: ... don't get the idea that you can drop jQuery on your project and soar like an eagle. I think it is very important to learn a little basic javascript before you start in on a framework. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edited version of the above answer. There was an issue with the `"value.replace(' ', '_');"` where it would only take the space out between the first two words typed in. This code snippet below does it for all.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

addEvent(document.getElementById('name'), 'keyup', function () {    
   document.getElementById('url').value = this.value.split(' ').join('');    
});    

function addEvent(ele, evnt, funct) {

  if (ele.addEventListener) // W3C    
    return ele.addEventListener(evnt,funct,false);

  else if (ele.attachEvent)  // IE    
    return ele.attachEvent("on"+evnt,funct);

}

</script>
```